# Reading value from a .txt file and writing it into output file

Tags: r, file-io

I am trying to read files from a folder, count them and then use for loop with length to go through each file, use `cat` function and for first file, put output in **output.txt** to be like:

- file1 : cat output
- file2 : cat output

My code looks like:

```
entry = list.files(path = "//Users//michael/Desktop//test_folder", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
output = list.files(path = "//Users//michael/Desktop//list.txt", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
len = length(entry)
for(i in 1){
cat(entry,file="//Users//michael/Desktop//list.txt", sep="\t", append=TRUE)
cat("\n",file="//Users//michael/Desktop//list.txt", append=TRUE)
}
```

I have also tried with `for(i in 1:len)` but that would just make this x3 longer because it does it for every iteration of 'i'.

My test_folder looks like:

- file 1.txt with the values (John, Michael, Fabian ) each one in a new line (\n)
- file 2.txt has similar values

To summarize:
I am trying to load my test_folder, count number of files (in my case 2), go through each file in for loop and `cat` them so I can see what's inside and then print values inside my list.txt (output) in a format like:

- file1: cat output
- file2: cat output

Where is my mistake and how would output/altered code look like in order to make this work?

Comment: Trying to understand what your objective is: What is the end product you are trying to produce?

Comment: @MichaelDavidson It's learning curve. I just want to go through files in folder (there will be .txt files only) > cat them and print their value in output.txt file. Just a learning curve. Later I will swap some code with functions that will do something else etc. Do you have any input how can i do this? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, if I understand you correctly, you'd like to open several .txt files from a single directory and then concatenate their contents. I recommend using `list.files` (like you already are) and then `lapply` and `readLines` to open those files.

Get the locations of the .txt files. This produces a list with each element of the list being a directory (file location):

```
dirs <- list.file(path="path/to/input/directory", full.path=TRUE)
```

Use lapply to iterate over the elements of the list (like your `for` loop) and open them with the function `readLines`. This produces a list with the same number of elements as `dirs`, but this time it contains the contents of the text files:

```
myfiles <- lapply(dirs, readLines)
```

Finally, combine these elements of the list (each containing the contents of one text file) into one object, which you can save as a single text file.

```
dat <- do.call("rbind", myfiles) # note rbind might need to be replaced with "c" depending on the contents of the .txt files
```

Sorry if I am missing something or misunderstood. Please comment and I will adapt accordingly.

Comment: This actually worked! I have a second question for you. Now I am trying to load image from some folder and using **mxnet** library get results of the image. For exmaple if I load image from folder and it has a rabbit on it, some sort of output should be like "it's 90% rabbit" . I have a version that works for 1 image, but now i am trying to alter it for more than one. That's why all this. Do you have any hint? :) Also thanks for solution

Comment: Glad that worked. I would check out some of these tutorials: http://mxnet.io/packages/r/index.html I haven't used that package. After you give it a try, you could post a new question though.